# Ubuntu 17.04 desktop amd64 version not connecting to jio-fi device

Tags: networking

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop 64-bit and have found that my USB WiFi adapter (Wayona mini USB) is not connecting to my jiofi device after I have put in the password. I clicked on the network menu, the drop-down menu showed the jiofi device, but when I click on connect, a message comes up that says "you are now disconnected". How can I get my computer to connect?

Comment: i am able to connect using the usb cable but not via wi-fi, though the drop down menu shows jiofi device.

Comment: Resetting your jiofi dongle may help.. it helped me... it will reset your wifi SSID and Password to default but you can change them later... Although I cannot find the proper reason why this problem occurred.. but resetting it helped.. may be you should try too

Comment: How to reset it ?

Comment: i now have solved the problem by upgrading to 17.10. after upgrading to 17.10 version, the connection happened automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have a jioFIBER 30mbps - it connects fine with my windows laptop/office windows laptop, but though connection for 2.4/5ghz is detected on my Ubuntu 20.04 - it just hangs while trying to connect.
I purchased a 3rd party router ( ASUS AX 5400 router) and then I could connect to the JIOfiber - using default settings!
So far I could not find out the reason or config required to connect directly to JIOFIBER, the support guys from JIO say I can get it resolved via a paid service visit - which I did not ask for yet